# When linking a binary or shared library, why do I have to pass in shared libraries I depend on?

Tags: c++, c, linker

Let's say I am trying to create a binary `myprogram`. `myprogram` includes a file `foo.h` which has some functions declared; those functions are defined in `libfoo.so`. Therefore, when building `myprogram`, I pass in `libfoo.so` to the linker...no, not the name "libfoo.so" but the actual shared library file.

My question is, why is this necessary? My understanding is that the shared library will be needed only at runtime, when the dynamic linker will load it into memory and fix up all references to it in `myprogram`. What is the static linker doing with `libfoo.so` other than putting its name into the list of shared libraries?

Answer (score 1):

> What is the static linker doing with `libfoo.so` other than putting its name into the list of shared libraries?

For producing a dynamic-linked executable, that's basically it! It also confirms that, with the versions of the shared libraries available at link time, all undefined symbol references get defined by one of the shared libraries. This property allows you to make meaningful build-time (autoconf style) tests, e.g. to make sure `libfoo.so` is a new enough version to have the `bar` function in it.

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing static and dynamic linked libraries. Dynamic libraries rely on a runtime module being loaded into memory and accesses what it needs via exported methods. Static libraries are actually embedded directly into your own binary rather than loaded separately.

Comment: I don't think OP is static linking. By "static linker" they seem to just mean the link stage of building.

Comment: Yes, I was talking about the link step that produces the binary.